# How to detect a Pivot item is selected in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am implementing the Pivot control in Windows Phone 7.

I want to know which Pivot item is selected and active after the user does a swipe gesture.

How to detect the swipe gesture event related to Pivot control?

Which delegate method should I use ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

SelectionChanged is the event to wire up to for detecting Pivot item changes.

As kP suggests, SelectedIndex/SelectedItem are the properties you can access to see which item is currently selected.

Here's an example event handler to show the SelectedIndex each time it changes.

```
    private void thisPivot_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(thisPivot.SelectedIndex);
    }
```

Comment: I've used something like this myself works great, you can always set a property here that is read elsewhere to get the currently selected pivot item.

Answer (score 10):

You could use the [Pivot.SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.pivot.selecteditem%28VS.92%29.aspx) method which is a getter and setter. This will allow you to return the current `PivotItem` the user is on. Alternatively, you could use the [Pivot.SelectedIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.pivot.selectedindex%28VS.92%29.aspx) method if you just want to access the indexes of each PivotItem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform an action once the PivotItem has actually finished loading entirely and transition animation sequence is complete, take a look at the [`LoadedPivotItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.pivot.loadedpivotitem%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) event.