# Pivot SelectedItem property

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I'd like to find which PivotItem is currently displaying but always I'm recieving null in `CommandParameter`. Here's the code:

`xaml`

```
<Pivot ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" x:Name="MainList">
    ...
</Pivot>

...

<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar>
        <AppBarButton Label="add item" Icon="Add" Command="{Binding AddElementCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MainList, Path=SelectedItem}" />            
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

`C#`

```
public DelegateCommand<object> AddElementCommand { get; set; }

public void Init()
{
    this.AddElementCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(this.AddElement);
}

private void AddElement(object category)
{
     ...
}
```

I'm 100% sure, that DelegateCommand implementation is working, because if I put in `CommandParameter` value `{Binding}`, then I'm recieving in `AddElement`'s parameter current ViewModel object.

Why binding through `ElementName` isn't working? Is it possible to bind Pivot's SelectedItem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could simply get the current `PivotItem` within a `Pivot` control using the `SelctionChanged` event.

This could help you:

[How to detect a Pivot item is selected in Windows Phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059425/)

Comment: Yes, but I'd like to use MVVM pattern and not to use behaviors if it's possible. In addition, I'm developing for Windows Phone 8.1 (XAML).